# using gulp-htmlbuild without concatenating all files into a single file

Tags: javascript, html, build, gulp

I want to:

1. Read all js files in htmlbuild:js block
2. Pipe them into a series of build steps like uglification, syntax check , ....,
3. Copy them (while preserving their directory structure) into a destination folder (html build target actually)
4. add link to ALL of them inside the htmlbuild:js again

The use case in [default example of the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlbuild#usage) is similar to what I want, but instead of steps 3 and 4, it simply concatenates all of them into a single file with a predefined name and writes a single script tag pointing to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `block` you receive in the htmlbuild callback function is a writable stream. Whatever you write to it will end up as the replacement of the block. In the case of the example there's only one path written to it but nothing prevents you from writing multiple:

```
// then write the build result path to it 
block.write('path1.js');
block.write('path2.js');
block.write('path3.js');
block.write('path4.js');
block.end();
```

Since it's also a readable stream you could just pipe it to itself or apply transformations to it:

```
// First build the files that are in the block
block
  .pipe(buildSteps)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(targetDir));

// Then rename all the paths and write back to the block
block
  .pipe(renameToDestination)
  .pipe(block);
```

In this example `renameToDestination` would be a transform stream that accepts the paths as strings and renames them to the target directory.

Comment: `block.pipe(block)` was what I want! But still a little bit of problem here!
when I use the `gulpSrc` function from [package example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlbuild#extended-example) to create source stream, all files in the stream lose their paths, and piping the stream into a `gulp.dest("myTarget")` will output all files in myTarget folder without preserving relative paths!

Comment: I kinda figured it out by passing `{base: "MySrcDirectory"}` to `gulp.src`'s second argument `options`